# Netbeans scala plugin problem , classes underlined with red line

Tags: scala, plugins, netbeans

Iam using netbeans6.9 (with scala plugin) and scala 2.8 on MacOSX.
The plugin works fine but when i refresh the scala project.
I see all the class are underlined with red line saying....

"illegal inheritance:
self-type  does not conform to scala.ScalaObject's selftype ScalaObject
ScalaObject doesnot have a constructor"

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the NB plugin. There are two ways to remove this error.

1. Right click inside any window with Scala code (i.e. any window with a .scala file open). Select "reset Scala parser". Then click on any other window and back to your scala code. The error should disappear
2. Restart the IDE.

This works for me in NB 6.8 on Windows. I assume the same would work on a Mac with NB 6.9.

There is a third option to just ignore this error (as it is only in the IDE but does not occur during compile).